# Which DSL is correct for performing a pre-filtered query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've looked back at some queries I have saved, and it appears I've managed to achieve essentially the same query in three different ways. They all return the same data, but which one is 'correct'? I.e., which one contains no superfluous code and is most performant?

Option 1

```
{
"query":{
   "bool":{
      "must":[
         {
            "match":{
               "event":"eventname"
            }
         },
         {
            "range":{
               "@timestamp":{
                  "gt":"now-70s"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
},
 "aggs":{
    "myterms":{
       "terms":{
          "field":"fieldname"
       }
    }
 }
}
```

Option 2

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "match":{
                        "event":"eventname"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range":{
                        "@timestamp":{
                           "gt":"now-70s"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "myterms":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"fieldname"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Option 3

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "match":{
                        "event":"eventname"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range":{
                        "@timestamp":{
                           "gt":"now-70s"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "myterms":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"fieldname"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If I were to guess, I'd go for Option 2, as the others appear that they might be running match as query. But the documentation is pretty confusing regarding the correct form that DSL queries should take.

Comment: Are you sure about option 2? `match` cannot be used in filters, only in queries? Option 2 should throw `org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException`. The `match` in option 3 only works because you've wrapped it in a `query` filter. (I know their naming can be confusing at times). Then it depends whether you need an exact match against `event` and `user` values or you're more after searching text.

Comment: Well, that narrows it down slightly. The "event":"eventname" should be just a simple comparison, no scoring or the like. What filter should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I'd go for option 2 but with a simple `term` filter for starters instead of `match` which isn't allowed in filters.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "event": "eventname"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gt": "now-70s"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "myterms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event"
      }
    }
  }
}
```